# JPA Add or update object

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I'm trying to save an object called Stat using EclipseLink. If the id exists in the db, update that object. If not, create a new object. Here is my object:

```
@Entity
public class Stat {

    @Column
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public long id;

    @JoinColumn
    @ManyToOne
    public User user;


    @Column
    public boolean accepted;

    @Column
    public boolean finished;

    public Stat() {
    }
}
```

And here is my method for adding/updating the object.

```
public long addReplaceStat(Stat stat) {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            Stat oldStat = em.find(Stat.class, stat.id);
            if (oldStat == null)
                em.persist(stat);
            else
                em.merge(stat);
            em.getTransaction().commit();

            em.getTransaction().begin();
            Stat newStat = em.find(Stat.class, stat.id);
            if (newStat != null)
                em.refresh(newStat);
            em.getTransaction().commit();

            return stat.id;
        }
```

My problem is that I get exception at em.refresh() saying "The attribute [id] of class [User] is mapped to a primary key column in the database. Updates are not allowed." And I don't understand why. Shouldn't refresh just update the values of my managed object without problem?

What is the best idiom to do what I want (add or update)?

Comment: can you add the stacdump of the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JPA spec says:

> The semantics of the merge operation applied to an entity X are as
>   follows:
>
> - If X is a detached entity, the state of X is copied onto a pre-existing managed entity instance X' of the same identity or a new
>     managed copy X' of X is created.
> - If X is a new entity instance, a new managed entity instance X' is created and the state of X is copied into the new managed entity
>     instance X'.
>
> [...]

So to add if not existing or update is it exists, you just need to do:

```
Stat attachedStat = em.merge(stat);
```

Regarding your problem with refresh, I don't know why it happens. But why are you refreshing an entity that you just loaded from the database? There is nothing to refresh.